# What does the 'Rebuild All' setting do?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, rebuild

In visual studio, there is an option to "Rebuild All" from the build menu, what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cleans every project in your solution and rebuilds all projects.

Comment: So it's like a Clean followed by a Build?

Comment: Clean and build is not the same as a rebuild (I haven't checked in VS2008, but in VS2005 performing a rebuild all certainly didn't clean the output directories)

Answer (score 1):

It does rebuilds everything from scratch, but sometimes you need to use clean to clear some old files that stack into the build environment...

I don't know why (yet) but experiences shows sometime a clean is necessary even using rebuild all..

Answer (score 0):

It ignores all dependencies between projects, and rebuilds every project in the solution (as if every source file has changed)

Answer (score 0):

An example of when you need to do a rebuild: When you change an embedded resource (e.g. xml file, image), you will need to do a rebuild to ensure that the changes are included in the program - embedded resources are not considered to be a dependency when compiling.