# What is included inside Rebuild All action in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio, rebuild

I understand a general idea of what Rebuild All option means from [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865325/what-does-the-rebuild-all-setting-do). I am more interested in what actions are included when you select to Rebuild all.

The reason why I am asking is because I work on a large project, where I perform a lot of manual maintenance, which includes updating service references. It is time consuming. But recently I found out that Updating Service reference is included into Rebuild All action. So, I would like to know that else is included, since I think it might help me to reduce manual maintenance time even further.

Microsoft blogs just gave general idea, I am addressing people who might have found it out on their own while working with it.